# LDAP loginShell on platforms with different paths

Tags: debian, ldap, freebsd, login, user-management

I'm using LDAP to deal with users and authentication across my network. I'm now adding FreeBSD hosts and have hit a problem with login shells. on Linux, shells tend to be in `/bin/$shellname`, so setting my login shell in LDAP to `/bin/zsh` works perfectly. on FreeBSD, `/bin/zsh` doesnt exist, I need to use `/usr/local/bin/zsh`. is there a solution to this? I imagine I might be able to make some sort of `login-shell.sh` script that LDAP passes out as the "shell" and then use the script to determine the actual shell for the user, but I'm not a fan of that idea.

I'm using Debian and FreeBSD, both with a standard OpenLDAP/PAM/nss setup.

**edit**: it looks like using `/bin/sh` and adding an `exec $shell` to `.profile` would "work", but that doesnt scale very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a directory /shell on each machine with symbolic links to the locations of the shells. That way the users that interest you could have a shell of /shell/zsh, /shell/bash and so on while the symbolic links locally take care of the actual location problem.

Comment: I like this idea because it matches with Puppet well. just add /shell and symlink creation to the $operatingsystem configs I aready run.